# stream audio from multiple android smartphones to pc or directly to an earphone and to listen

Tags: audio, microphone, streaming, audio-recording

I would like to know if it is possible to achieve a setup in which I'm able to listen to multiple android phones via streaming audio to pc which may be streamed through usb or via bluetooth.

Or if there is an alternative through transmitting to a device and just connecting that device with some earphones and I would be able to hear all devices at the same time?

Here is the overall picture of this last solution

[image: androidexchange]